# Libgdx - multiple images in a group, best practices - also overdraw question

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to right a card game, that will have an image in the middle, a coloured border and potentially a symbol in the top left. I am using libgdx and a stage/scene2d.

The image will change depending on the suit *(these are not your normal 52 deck type of cards)*, the border colour will change to match the suit, though this colour can be pre determined by the user so I can't pre-save coloured images *(though I guess I could pre save about 15 diff colours and give the user a choice of 15)* and the symbol will only be on some cards and not others.

[image: first card]

[image: second card]

As you can see from the two images I've added I have two diff images, border colours and symbols.

My question is relating to groups and overdraw.

1. I presume I should set up a group with 3 images in, and I'm hoping having this won't slow my game down as I will have potentially 30 cards on screen at once and 30 groups with up to 3 images in each could be a lot to draw. Is this right and will LibGDX be able to handle it fine?
2. How should I do the coloured border? Should I have the entire card a coloured rectangle and the image drawn on top? Would the draw method be trying to draw the coloured section underneath the image and thus wasting GPU/CPU time?

   A friend of mine said I could just have a white image, and then set the colour using RGB values in the code? Is this possible? That would mean I could only have a single jpg which would be much better for apk size.
3. Or should I ignore using a jpg image and try and draw the coloured square using ShapeRenderer?

Thanks, I hope these questions aren't too many in one post.